# When did this character have a change of heart?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

In the *Legion* third season finale, it is revealed that Farouk was influencing (at least I think...) David to change his past so that he never gets possessed by Farouk (Shadow King).

But when did he have this change of heart? After discovering David has a time-traveler by his side? Or even during his season 2 stint?

Comment: I think the whole point of that series is mereology -- something like Ship of Thesis Paradox where you don't really know who a character really is or what they *really want until they profess/express what they want, but Legion had plenty of "spin-on-dime" moments like this, in which sometimes the characters either never ask the right questions (Syd--->Shadow King), or they go along with things just because. In terms of this Q, I think in his own toxic way, TSK always loved David, but to try and figure out when and for how long "this" was his plan, I think will be moot.